# Cannot get orientation of the image using Exif interface and Media Store for Pixel phones

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently trying to fetch orientation of image when captured from pixel phones to rotate it correctly. After debugging Exif Interface class observed that there is no TAG_ORIENTATION present in the image (which means there is no exif data). When fetching through the MediaStore observed that there is no column returned from the cursor as well.

```
 val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream!!)
            val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
            val matrix = Matrix()
            var rotation = 0f
            when (orientation) {
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotation = 90f
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotation = 180f
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotation = 270f
            }
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("exif_orientation", orientation)
            firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("exif", bundle)
            matrix.postRotate(rotation)
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap!!, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.width, scaledBitmap.height, matrix, true)
```

`Update`

I was able to fetch the TAG_ORIENTATION after adding permissions to the app for camera.But it is always zero, Android OS P and Q

Comment: Version Android Q?

Comment: `there is no TAG_ORIENTATION present in the image (which means there is no exif data). ` That is a bad conclusion.

Comment: Yes Android Q there is also a thread on reddit in which people are discussing this.
https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/8z8fm3/is_google_camera_app_not_saving_exif_data_anymore/

Comment: In order to reproduce the same you need to use Pixel 3a emulator, then you have to install Google Camera through play store on it and then while using the camera intent choose google cam and see the results

Comment: You should first post complete reproducable code before we take action.

Comment: You know you need to request an exif permission on Q?

Comment: Most likely, this has little to do with the phone. Camera apps are responsible for filling in EXIF tags. There is no requirement that they do so. Hence, not all camera apps will fill in those tags, and those that do might have bugs. Plus, images on an Android device can come from anywhere in the world -- not all are taken by a camera on that specific device. Not all images will have EXIF tags. Use EXIF tags where they exist, but do not assume that every image will have any given EXIF tag.

Comment: See your link for DP5 update.

Comment: I have found this in the release notes of Android 10, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all
Which states that there is a change in camera behavior. But I am still not able to find a solution to it.

Comment: @blackapps I found that this problem is in both Q and P can be found in the release notes. Adding the permission does allows you to get the exif tag, but the value is always zero